# How can I force Matlab to use all cores of my laptop?

Tags: matlab, performance

How can I force Matlab to use all cores of my laptop (Linux Mint)?

Does Matlab automatically parallelize the execution of my code?

Comment: This question has already been answered in Matlab answers:  https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/333779-why-isn-t-matlab-using-the-full-cpu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you start a parallel pool in matlab, it uses all the cores available in your PC.

Matlab doesn't automatically parallelize your code, it is your job to parallelize it.

Comment: How can I start a paralel pool?